# Intel OpenCL Vs. Khronos OpenCL

Tags: opencl

What is the difference between Intel, AMD and Khronos OpenCLs. I am totally new to OpenCL and want to start with it. I don't know which one is better to install on my operating system.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OpenCL is an *"extension" to C and C++ languages that enables parallelization* of software on your compute devices: CPU, GPU, etc.

OpenCL is defined by a standard (**created by Khronos Group**) and **implemented by hardware vendors Intel, AMD, nVidia, etc.**. So *each OpenCL implementation requires a vendor specific OpenCL driver* that will enable the usage of the vendor's hardware.

So to conclude, **if you have an Intel based system, use the Intel OpenCL** because only so you would be able to use all compute devices in your machine. The same goes if you have an AMD system. Also, take note that there is no Khronos OpenCL implementation.

Of course you can have a platform with OpenCL enabled devices from multiple vendors (e.g. Intel CPU+GPU and nVidia discrete card). In this case the OpenCL runtime contains a generic layer (a dynamic loaded library). This layer is an interface which calls the implementations provided in each device driver depending on the selected OpenCL platform.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

So, it is something like OpenGL that every platform has its own implementation but the khronos just define what should be in the next version and so on. Is that true?

Comment: but for example, for opengl we can use the windows implementation or linux one without installing nVIDIA or ATI implementation but the opencl does not have in-operating system implementation.

Comment: I'm not sure about this but I think that the OpenGL implementation is integrated in the graphics driver. So when you download the graphics driver on Windows you get a specific implementation of OpenGL. Perhaps on linux you have a HW agnostic implementation.

Comment: Most modern GPU drivers include an OpenCL runtime. If you find or build clInfo you can tell if you have one. If your GPU doesn't have a runtime, install the Intel runtime and if your CPU has SSE4.2 then you can use OpenCL on the CPU.

Comment: @VAndrei if I have an Intel CPU+GPU (integrated HD Graphics) and another nVidia GPU, can I both? How does it work in terms of drivers?

Comment: @manatttta see my updated response. Basically you have a generic interface which calls the corresponding OpenCL implementation depending in what platform was selected in the code.

Comment: When you write your program, host and kernel, all you care are the headers, which are provided by Khronos. When you link compiled object files to an executable or library, you need to link to run time libraries, aka implementation or driver. Usually when you install driver for GPU, opencl libraries should also be installed. One exception is Intel GPU driver for Linux does not include OpenCL runtime: you need to download/build/install yourself, like a open-sourced one backed by Intel called Beignet(google for "intel beignet opencl").

Comment: However, for kernel code, each implementation has different extensions: AMD supports dot product up to float16 while OpenCL standard only support up to float4. Intel Beignet supports `static inline` functions and `static const` variables while other implementation don't. The portability issue between nVidia and AMD kernel code is also widely discussed.

Answer (score 1):

OpenCL is a standard defined by Kronos. They [distribute header files](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/OpenCL-Headers) that you have to give to your compiler. They do not distribute binaries to link against. For that, you must get an ICD (Installable Client Driver), on Windows this is in the form of a DLL file. You will get it from installing one or more of...

- [Nvidia drivers](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx) (if you have an Nvidia GPU)
- [AMD drivers](http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/OpenCL2-Driver.aspx) (if you have an AMD GPU or an AMD CPU)
- [Intel Drivers](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/opencl-drivers) (if you have an Intel CPU, also some Intel CPU's have built in GPU's).

Do not worry about compiling against one vendor and it not working on another, OpenCL has been carefully designed to work around this. Compile against any version you have, it will work with any other version that is the same or newer, regardless of who made it.

**Be Aware**, the AMD OpenCL driver will operate as an OpenCL driver for Intel CPU's. If, for example, you have an AMD GPU and an Intel CPU, and have installed the Intel OpenCL driver **and** the AMD OpenCL driver, the AMD driver will report that it can provide both a GPU device and a CPU device (your CPU), and the Intel driver will report having a CPU device (also your CPU) and most likely also a GPU device (the GPU that is on the Intel CPU die, for example on an i7-3770, this will be a HD4000). If you blindly ask OpenCL for "All CPU's available" you will get the AMD drivers and the Intel drivers offering you the *same CPU*. Your code will not run very well in this case.

On Windows it is expected that you will [download the header files](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/OpenCL-Headers) yourself, and then either create a library from the DLL (MSVC), or link directly against the DLL (Mingw & Clang default behavior).

On Linux, you package manager will likely have a library to link against, consult your distributions documentation regarding this. On Ubuntu and Debian this command will work...

```
sudo apt-get install ocl-icd-opencl-dev
```

On Mac, there is nothing to install, and trying to install something will likely damage your system. Just install Xcode, and use the framework "OpenCL".

There are other platforms, for example Android. Some FPGA vendors offer OpenCL libraries. Consult your vendors documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Khronos defines OpenCL standard. Each vendor/ open source will implement that standards.

Khronos defines set of conformance tests which need to pass if a vendor claims that his opencl implementation is as per standard.